# Regex: Invert Match order

Tags: c#, regex, search, ienumerable

i have this snippet to perform a regex-search:

```
public IEnumerable<MyMatch> GetMyMatches() 
{
   Match m = myRegex.Match(Text, offset);
   if (m != null && m.Success && m.Value != null && m.Value.Length > 0)
   {
      offset = m.Index+m.Length;
      yield return new MyMatch() { Match=m, SomeFurtherInformation=... };
   } else
   yield break;
}
```

As you can see, i walk down all occourences in my text.

but how to inverse the search-direction?

thanks for your help

Comment: Note: m != null is always true and so is m.Value != null unless there is an exception (like offset too much big) but then there is no m :-) If there is no match, Value == "".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use '[Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx)' then do a '[Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)' on the returned IEnumerable.

Comment: +1, and `Matches` guarantees that you won't run into an infinite loop in case of a zero-length match (see Remarks on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9ee7wwd.aspx), contrary to your current code.

Answer (score 2):

There's a RightToLeft option in [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - you may have to adjust your expression too, but that will search "backwards" for you.